# Get a complete list of all categories using node-wpapi

Tags: wp-api

I'm trying to get a complete list of all categories using node-wpapi. But I can not do that.

I use `wp.categories()`, but it only returns a response containing up to 10 categories.
Actually, there are 12 categories.

The codes I used below.

```
wp.categories().then( (res) => {
    console.log(res.length);
});
```

```
let categories = await wp.categories();
console.log(categories.length);
```

Both codes above returned `10`.

Is there an optional argument or other methods to get a complete list of all categories?
What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried `wp.categories().perPage( 12 )` ? For > 100 you will need paging, `wp.categories().perPage( 100 ).page( 2 )` ?

Comment: @Pierogi, I just wanted to add that you can find more details about the `perPage()` method here: http://wp-api.org/node-wpapi/using-the-client/#paging--sorting and http://wp-api.org/node-wpapi/collection-pagination/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, birgire!
Both `.perPage()` and `.page()` worked!